I encounter an error while I try to create Java project on visual studio code and I have install the Java extension pack
The Error:
Java_home not found in your environment.
Please set the java_home variable in your environment to match the location of your installation

I tried to create a small project in Visual Studio code so I installed the Java extension pack, and it keeps displaying this error message, I have tried to make some changes in my system environment but it still not working out, I use Java-Maven, maven-archetype-quickstart, version 1.4 I expect it to run smoothly.

First try running java-version to make sure you have it installed. Then search for Environment Variables  and select edit the system Environment Variables. then click on Environment Variables. Under System Variables click new, to add a new variable---- variable name: JAVA_HOME
variable value: The path to your JDK installation (e.g., C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1).
then click ok

Open Visual Studio Code.
Go to File > Preferences > Settings (or press Ctrl+,).
Search for java.home.
Enter the path to your JDK installation (same as what you set for JAVA_HOME) in the input field.

Do basic settings.

press ShortKey (Ctrl+Shift+P) : Command Palette
select "Java: Configure Java Runtime"
see which JDKs are used for your projects


Vscode Java Development Pack default depend on your system JDK, if you not install, try install it by following this toturial https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/jdk_howto.html
If you installed, open the VS Code terminal and run java --version to check whether JAVA_HOME is added to your PATH. If everything is correct, it will print the Java version. If an error occurs, you should set the environment variable by following this link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html
